# IDEA java/maven - sometimes doesnt detect generated sources in directory marked "generated sources root"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Idea 2020.3 (same with 2020.1)

I have a maven based project.
A folder is marked "generated source root"
Generated .java source files are inside
I have a "build-helper-maven" plugin with add-sources in phase "initialize"

"Sometimes" when I start up wildfly with "before launch"
"build",
"build 4 artifacts" (maven) options

then IDEA tells me it doesnt find the source file. When I look it up with shift+shift the file is there. The folder is marked "generated source root".

When I use maven compile in IDEA, on next startup IDEA finds the file.
What can I do so IDEA always finds files which are there?

I think IDEA sometimes rebuilds its index partially and doesnt scan the folder with the generated-files, so it thinks they are NOT there.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Is it reproducible with every project?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this annoyance too.  The caching/indexing can be flaky e.g. I've seen old source code after click on a stack trace for a maven dependency, I had earlier clean install built on another IDEA window, before that run! File - Invalidate Caches and Restart can be useful.